# Can I do insert group of record by one query in Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure

To increase performance I need to insert group of records by one query. This records can be in different partiotions. Is it possible to do?

Does anyone do somthing like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it?  If not then please do try it, and then if it doesn't work you might consider rewriting your question telling us what you've tried and what error message(s) you get.

Comment: Thaks for attention. Now I read about azure tables and try to realize how to do my task. In case of transaction I can't use records of different sections in one transaction. But I no need transactions I just need to insert group of records

Comment: I can't try at this moment, but if someone have this experiance it would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I often do this to increase performance (not so much for the cost). The advantage here is that you only serialize once and the whole operation acts as a transaction. This means all your changes will all succeed or all will fail.

I don't really know what you mean by multiple sections? Do you mean multiple partitions? This is not possible, all entities should be in the same partition (and limited to 100 items per batch).

Here is a very detailed explaination: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx

Comment: Yes, I meant partitions. 
Thaks a lot for reply